# Python UDP VideoStreaming with CV2

Tags: python, sockets, udp, video-streaming

Python27. I am trying to stream the video from camera between client and server apps.
I am learning python from couple of days... I have already learned that to send the data over UDP I need to serialize the data... I have found the pickle library but the code does not work for me. Is there something more regarding data serialization to be able to send the data over the network? How to divide that into smaller parts of data? When i check the type it says that it is string with the size of about 1MB or even more. I guess that's why I'm getting the error:

*socket.error: [Errno 10040] A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself*

TCP version of this worked fine, but performance was poor. I wanted to try with UDP
Here's my code:

```
__AUTHOR__=u"DK"

import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct


def StartStreamSending():
    u"""
    Funkcja przesyłająca stream z lokalnej kamery[0] na serwer.
    """
    UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
    UDP_PORT = 8012
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    #result, img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', frame)
    #img_str2 = np.array(img_str)

    #pik = pickle.Pickler()
    #frame = np.reshape(frame, (240,320,3))
    data = np.array(frame)
    dataToSend = pickle.dumps(data)
    size = sys.getsizeof(dataToSend)
    print(size)
    print(type(dataToSend));

    clientsocket.sendto(dataToSend, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

StartStreamSending()
```

And the server:

```
__AUTHOR__=u"DK"

import socket
import sys
import cv2
import pickle
import numpy as np
import struct

HOST='localhost'
PORT=8012

def WaitAndReceiveVideoStream(_strHOST, _iPORT):
    u"""
    Funkcja odbierająca stream z kamery klienta.

    """
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print 'Socket created'

    s.bind((_strHOST,_iPORT))
    print 'Socket bind complete'



    data = ""
    #payload_size = struct.calcsize("L")

    i = 0
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(512)
        frame=pickle.loads(data)
        i = i + 1
        print 'coming frame' + str(i)
        #frame = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=numpy.uint8)
        #frame = numpy.reshape(frame, (240,320,3))
        #if 3 == i :
        #    cv2.SaveImage("C:\\image.",frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame) 
        cv2.waitKey(4) #Important delay - for test try 2 or 4 value.
        s.close()

WaitAndReceiveVideoStream(HOST, PORT)
```

Comment: The error you are getting actually says it all. You are trying to send too much data in one UDP datagram. You need to split the image, tag the chunks so you know their proper order (UDP doesn't guarantee that packets will arrive in any particular order) and assemble them back on the server.

Comment: and how can I do that? Doesn't the pickle.loads do that?

Comment: No. pickle provides the ability to save and restore a logical structure to/from binary format. The tagging and re-ordering @nebril referred to is essentially what TCP provides. If you want to do the same thing with UDP, it's possible, but you'll have to do the TCP-equivalent function yourself. You need to split the data into multiple smaller pieces, tag each of those with a sequence number (or equivalent), and be ready to re-order / re-assemble the pieces on the receiving end and then have a mechanism to support re-transmitting any pieces that got dropped in transit.

Comment: Thank you Gil! Well... I dont cary about aby drops, because it is video streaming. I don't need to retransmit that, some glitches are totally okay. Actually I've managed to do the steaming by simply decreasing the size of the image and compressing before the send out.

Comment: @reybanger can you explain how you have achieved successful streaming through compression?? Sample codes will be very much useful. Please...      Thanks in advance...